# Nuxt deployment and IE 11

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, iis, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am heading toward my first Nuxt deployment, of a large internal application. And I’d like to support IE 11, at least for a while. But when I generate the deployment files and attempt to access a staging site with IE, I immediately receive a syntax error from one of the generated js files.

Here’s a start at specifics:

Vue 2.6.12
Nuxt 2.14.6
Vuetify 2.3.2

Nuxt plugins for axios, auth, and a few other plugins.

The application is deployed to IIS, using nuxt generate and copying the dist directory to the server. I have tried using the generate command with and without the modern -m flag. There is no possibility of deploying other than through IIS (client specification), and I’d prefer not to have to run Node there, since the static deployment should work.

I am developing on a Mac and thus have no practical way to run and access the dev version by IE.

The application works properly on modern browsers, but throws an immediate syntax error in IE.

My understanding was that an IE-compatible version would be transpiled during the generate process, but evidently I’ve missed something.

As I say, this is my first Vue/Nuxt deployment, so any advice would be appreciated. I’ll be happy to provide any further specifics.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on what/how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps

- Check if the syntax error is caused due to any dependency. I ran into syntax error when using vue-calendar plugin. This plugin has problem with IE11
- Try adding `pollyfill.io` into your application. Inside your `nuxt.config.js` try adding inside `head`

  `script: [{ src: 'https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js' }]`
- If adding to `nuxt.config.js` doesn't work , try using the code into your `app.html` file

Comment: Thanks very much for you reply. As to the dependencies, I'm well aware that the issue might be there. But I have a number of external dependencies, and I don't know of any way to find out which might be the problem without removing them one by one, which will take lots more time than I have at the moment. If you have thoughts on a simpler way to test the dependencies, please let me.

I'll try polyfill. Hopefully, that will make a difference. Thanks again.